# No result defined for action and result input

Tags: struts2

I am using Struts2

I get error as no result defines for action and result input

```xml
<action name="update" method="updatePhase" class="Project">
   <result name="updated">/Project.jsp</result>
</action>
```

My action is not passing to my java class.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 45):

The error message means that an result named `input` has not been defined for your action. The result `input` is a default result returned by Struts when there is a problem with validating the parameters passed to an action. Thus, I recommend to **check and ensure that the parameters you are passing from your HTML form match the parameters of your action**. Check spelling, data types etc.

Comment: Also, make sure that you did not define an input with the same id more than once

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error and I changed my struts.xml file

```
from
<action name="Registeration101" class="Registeration101">
        <result name="success">pages/inputform.jsp</result>
        <result name="done">pages/quoteSuccess.jsp</result>
    </action>
 to
    <action name="Registeration101" class="Registeration101">
        <result name="success">pages/inputform.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">pages/inputform.jsp</result>
        <result name="done">pages/quoteSuccess.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

basically result name="input" was not defined

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you are coming from x.jsp.

Some times when you put validation annotation in your bean class, you are using in your Action and do not provide
x.jsp  ,exception is thrown.

If you do not want to validate the input simply remove the validation annotation from the bean class.

Answer (score 2):

The most common case is the presence of convention plugin. Look for that anything with a "convention" in it and remove that. A more detailed description will follow soon.

Comment: I'm looking forward to the more detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to specify a result with the name "input" for the action. This is how I solved my problem via the annotation.

Before:

```
@Action(value = "sendFeedback", results = {
    @Result(name = SUCCESS,type = "json"),
    @Result(name = ERROR,type = "json")})
```

After:

```
@Action(value = "sendFeedback", results = {
    @Result(name = SUCCESS,type = "json"),
    @Result(name = INPUT, type = "json"),
    @Result(name = ERROR,type = "json")})
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer - happens when you provide a wrong input . 
For example - if you have a field named "firstName" which is of type char and if you provide a wrong input ( like , int )

Answer (score 0):

```
<action name="update" method="updatePhase" class="Project">
   <result name="updated">/Project.jsp</result>
   <result name="input">/Project.jsp</result> <!-- add input return type as well in your struts.xml -->
</action>
```

Generally your execute()/updatePhase() in controller returning updated if everything goes fine .
But there are other return types which struts will take care .

You can handle it manually by defying your return values and corresponding

```
<result name="yourReturnValue">/Project.jsp</result>
```

Within inside the corresponding  tag.

Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have overridden the validate method in your class file (class="project" in your case), then it requires the necessary input values that you use in the validate method.
You can either pass the necessary values or change some validations in the validate method.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to give fully qualified name under the tag `class=""` in `struts.xml` . Then 
it will start passing your action.

Answer (score -1):

The Result name in *Action* and *struts.xml* should be equal. Still if you are getting this error it may be jar file issue. Try to add this jar file in to your library: `javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar`.